# Integrate JIRA with Cucumber on Fail Test Case

Tags: java, cucumber, jira, cucumber-jvm, qaf

I had an example of code in github that create jira ticket when automation test case failed. It collect the ITestResult information and used that to create ticket.

I can use @After on each test scenario but that is too many repetitive code. I want to execute once in the final test execution -  something in the hooks or listener.

Questions:
Is there any similar mechanism in cucumber to simulate ITestResult? Is it possible to use QAF library?

```
@Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
            JiraPolicy jiraPolicy = result.getMethod().getConstructorOrMethod().getMethod().getAnnotation(JiraPolicy.class);
            boolean isTicketReady = jiraPolicy.logTicketReady();
            if (isTicketReady) {
                // raise jira ticket:
                System.out.println("is ticket ready for JIRA: " + isTicketReady);
                JiraServiceProvider jiraSp = new JiraServiceProvider("https://naveenautomationlabs.atlassian.net",
                        "naveenanimation20@gmail.com", "jaizMlfaUkTfffNOVPq29B29", "TA");
                String issueSummary = result.getMethod().getConstructorOrMethod().getMethod().getName()
                        + "got failed due to some assertion or exception";
                String issueDescription = result.getThrowable().getMessage() + "\n";
                issueDescription.concat(ExceptionUtils.getFullStackTrace(result.getThrowable()));
    
                jiraSp.createJiraTicket("Bug", issueSummary, issueDescription, "Naveen");
            }
    
        }
```

Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

QAF tries to provide seamless user experience and features regardless of test authoring approach used. This case is use of [meta-data](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/scenario-meta-data.html) with test case.

When authoring test case in BDD approach, BDD syntax has meta-data statement that can be used. BDD2 syntax, meta-data can be provided as separate key value pair:
**Example BDD syntax:**

```
Scenario: scenario in BDD syntax
Meta-data: {'logTicketReady':true,'groups':['smoke','p1']}
   Given ...
   When ...
End
```

**Example BDD2:**

```
@smoke @p1
@logTicketReady:true
Scenario: scenario in BDD2 syntax
   Given ...
   When ...
```

When authoring test case in java meta data can be provided with custom annotation (for example in your case `JiraPolicy`) or `Metadata` annotation.

**Example Java:**

```
@MetaData("{'logTicketReady':true}")
@Test(groups={"smoke","p1"})
public void sampleJavaTest(){
  //implementation goes here
}
```

If you have created custom annotation, you can use it as well.

**Example Java with custom annotation:**

```
@JiraPolicy(logTicketReady=true)
@Test(groups={"smoke","p1"})
public void sampleJavaTest(){
  //implementation goes here

}
```

For execution, use appropriate factory class in xml [configuration](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/bdd-configuration.html).

The method you shared can be modified as below to work with both Coded and BDD approach.

```
@Override
public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
        TestNGScenario scenario = (TestNGScenario) result.getMethod();
        Map<String, Object> metadata = scenario.getMetaData();
      
        boolean isTicketReady = (boolean)metadata.getOrDefault("logTicketReady",false);
        if (isTicketReady) {
            // raise jira ticket:
            System.out.println("is ticket ready for JIRA: " + isTicketReady);
            JiraServiceProvider jiraSp = new JiraServiceProvider("https://naveenautomationlabs.atlassian.net",
                    "naveenanimation20@gmail.com", "jaizMlfaUkTfffNOVPq29B29", "TA");
            String issueSummary = metadata.get("name")
                    + "got failed due to some assertion or exception";
            String issueDescription = result.getThrowable().getMessage() + "\n";
            issueDescription.concat(ExceptionUtils.getFullStackTrace(result.getThrowable()));

            jiraSp.createJiraTicket("Bug", issueSummary, issueDescription, "Naveen");
        }

    }
```

**Note**: Cucumber is not mandatory when using QAF. Still if you want to use standard Cucumber runner or have cucumber-5 step implementation you need to use [qaf-cucumber](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-cucumber#qaf-cucumber). If you have step implementation in cucumber 1.x refer [documentation](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/gherkin_client.html#how-to-use-it)

Comment: I don't understand what u try to say here. Please provide some concrete examples on how to convert ITestListener to BDD cucumber or QAF approach.

Comment: When using `BDDTestFactory2` you will be able to use `ITestListener` so you can use your original method with minor modification as explained above. Use `BDDTestFactory2` to run your feature files as TestNG test.  Refer https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/bdd-configuration.html

Comment: After reading the documentation, i feel confused. It doesn't provide step by step guide. Anyone can help me with the step by step guide? Thanks.

Comment: Can you share what is the current state, what you have in place at present and how you are running your test?  Also share details of libraries used  in your current project with version. If you are going to start new project, you can go through qaf-step-by-step https://qmetry.github.io/qaf-step-by-step-tutorial/

Comment: I am still using AbstractTestNGCucumberTests runner haven't change anything yet but have have add qaf qaf-support library to the project.

Comment: use `BDDTestFactory2` instead of `AbstractTestNGCucumberTests`. You don't need to create runner class instead of that you just need to create run configuration file.  Refer https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/bdd-configuration.html to create XML configuration. Furthermore it looks you have cucumber step implementation. If it is cucumber 1.x you need to add `@StepProvider` annotation in  java file declaring steps at class level. If it is cucumber 5 you need to add [qaf-cucumber](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-cucumber#qaf-cucumber) dependency in your project

Comment: I would recommend to [checkout sample project](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-blank-project-maven) and play with it and then you can do the needful to your original project